# Using shared libraries from one R package in Rcpp code in my own package

Tags: r, rcpp

I am writing some C++ code (to be part of my own R package), which uses the Nexus Class Library (https://github.com/mtholder/ncl). There already exists an R package, rncl (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rncl/index.html) that uses this library: the /libs folder of this package contains what are presumably compiled versions of the library (rncl.so and rncl.so.dSYM).

My question is this: how best to write my R package to use the Nexus Class Library in a way that does not require a user to themselves build the Nexus Class Library?

I am hopeful that all I need to do is to make my package depend on rncl, and to add an appropriate entry to the PKG_LIBS line in my Makevars and Makevars.win file. If I am correct on this, what should I write to ensure my C++ code can use rncl.so in the /libs folder of the rncl package?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  But no, in general you _cannot_ simply rely on the shared library of another package.  Feel free to look at / for older questions here: package building with Rcpp in the context of R packages has been discussed before (as well as at other places).

Comment: Many thanks for the response - that answers my question. I'll keep looking for other solutions. One of which, I suppose, might be to include a build of Nexus Class Library in my own package, just as the authors of rncl did.

Comment: PS Thanks Dirk so much for all of your work on Rcpp and surrounding packages - they are tremendous.

Comment: Ok - I found Thirteen Simple Steps for Creating An R Package
with an External C++ Library (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-libraries.pdf), and will work from there.

Comment: You're welcome.  And I think I just referenced that vignette again within the last five or ten answers to `rcpp` question here.  It is a common question; that does not mean it is easy or trivial.  You will now 'own' builds of the ncl library on different platforms :-/  But hey at least there is one stanza package to look at.